# How to start ThreadGroup in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, threadgroup

I want to start a `ThreadGroup` which contains many threads, but the `start()` method is not present in the `ThreadGroup` class. It has a `stop()` method to stop the thread group though.
How can I start the thread group if the `start()` method is not available?

Please see the below code, I can start thread one by one but cannot start the thread group, because `start()` method is not present in `ThreadGroup` class. The requirement is we need to start thread group at the same time, how can this be done?

```
public class ThreadGroupExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    ThreadGroup thGroup1 = new ThreadGroup("ThreadGroup1");

    /* createting threads and adding into thread grout "thGroup1" */
    Thread1 th1 = new Thread1(thGroup1, "JAVA");
    Thread1 th2 = new Thread1(thGroup1, "JDBC");
    Thread2 th3 = new Thread2(thGroup1, "EJB");
    Thread2 th4 = new Thread2(thGroup1, "XML");

    /* starting all thread one by one */
    th1.start();
    th2.start();
    th3.start();
    th4.start();

    // thGroup1.start();

    thGroup1.stop();

    }
}

class Thread1 extends Thread
{
    Thread1(ThreadGroup tg, String name)
    {
    super(tg, name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ThreadGroup tg = getThreadGroup();
        System.out.println(getName() + "\t" + i + "\t" + getPriority()
            + "\t" + tg.getName());
    }
    }
}

class Thread2 extends Thread
{

    Thread2(String name)
    {
    super(name);
    }

    Thread2(ThreadGroup tg, String name)
    {
    super(tg, name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ThreadGroup tg = getThreadGroup();
        System.out.println(getName() + "\t" + i + "\t" + getPriority()
            + "\t" + tg.getName());
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `ThreadGroup` is not going to be able to start all its threads for the simple reason that the threads are actually added to the group only when they are started. Note that the **deprecated and dangerous** `stop()` and `suspend()` methods in `ThreadGroup` merely run the same kind of sequential loop you are trying to avoid anyway.

Comment: @RealSkeptic are you sure it is a duplicate though? I stipulate to the fact that the dup is what the OP is after, but the question is about a different topic/issue which is not explained in the dup. Please reconsider this.

Comment: @Idos I believe in its current form its an XY problem, in which the actual problem is a duplicate and the `ThreadGroup` question is only secondary to it. Your answer and my comment give enough information to explain why ThreadGroup is irrelevant to solve this problem, but any real answer to the OP would actually be an answer to the dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html):

> A thread group represents a set of threads.

It is not *designed* to `.start()` multiple threads at the same time.

You can add `Threads` to the group, or other `ThreadGroups`, which can access other `Thread`s' state, but not start a `ThreadGroup` together. A `Thread` is allowed to access information about its own `ThreadGroup`, but not to access information about its `ThreadGroup`'s parent `ThreadGroup` or any other `ThreadGroups`.

For some more info about the available functions with example of usage read [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/java_lang_threadgroup.htm).